# Generating the sequence 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ... in Python

Tags: python, loops, sequence, modulo

Using `% 2` gives me the alternating sequence `[0, 1, 0, 1, ...]`

```
seq = []
for i in range(10):
    e = i % 2
    seq.append(e)
```

Is there a way to generate the sequence `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,...]` by generating the element **from inside the loop**?

```
seq = []
for i in range(10):
    e = the_solution(i)
    seq.append(e)
```

Comment: Why are there two reopen votes here? It looks like a clear duplicate to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you want to slow your existing sequence down, effectively doubling the length of each element. That is, indices 0 and 1 of your new sequence should correspond to index 0 of your old; 2 and 3 of your new sequence should correspond to index 1 of the old; and so on. We can use integer division to get this behavior.

```
e = (i // 2) % 2
```

`//` is like `/` but it rounds down to the next integer, so `2 // 2` and `3 // 2` are both `1`.